# loop in vector c++ using iterator

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code:

```
std::vector<A>::iterator it;
for(auto it = m_vA.begin(); it != m_vA.end(); it++)
```

and I gon an error:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'it' with no type
cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<A* const*, std::vector<tp::Vehicule*, std::allocator<A*> > >' to 'int' in initialization
```

and If I remove the auto

```
erreur: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = ((const B*)this)->B::m_vA.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = A*, _Alloc = std::allocator<A*>]()'
```

B is the class with my loop

Thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using ? What are the compilation flags if you are using gcc ?

Comment: Looks like `m_VA` is `const` in this context, so it requires, `std::vector<A>::const_iterator it;`.  To use `auto`, you need to enable `C++11` features by passing `-std=c++11` to your compiler.

Comment: Going by your error, `m_vA` is of type `std::vector<A*>`, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `auto` you seem not to have c++11 enabled, if you enable it, you should remove this line:

```
std::vector<A>::iterator it;
```

If you cannot use c++11 and for error after you remove auto, looks like you put this code into const method, so replace iterator with const_iterator:

```
std::vector<A>::const_iterator it;
for(it = m_vA.begin(); it != m_vA.end(); it++)
```

You can also make it one line, if you do not need this iterator after the loop:

```
for(std::vector<A>::const_iterator it = m_vA.begin(); it != m_vA.end(); it++)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are in a `const` method, you should use `const_iterator`, or remove the `const`.

And `auto` isn't needed if you declare your variable before. It won't produce an error, just a warning, but you've got to choose one way or the other ;)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem **remove** `auto` keyword.

You must have C++11 enabled to use `auto` like that. If you are using gcc compiler, you can enable it by `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` compiler's switch.

Currently it's using `auto` keyword inherited by older C compilers which simply will be omited. Compiler thinks you're declaring `it` again but without type.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have C++11 enabled, then why are you using `auto` like this? Simply use a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto i : m_vA)
    // do stuff here with i
```

Also, the problem with your code is that you specified the type of `it`, so there's no point in using `auto` in the for loop. Again, if you're using C++11, you should use the above loop, because it's far easier to write and understand.